# Prolog: process_create doesn't work inside http_handler

Tags: http, server, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to modify my website to allow users to call a particular program I'm working on. When I use `process_create/3` in Prolog "normally", i.e., from the REPL, then everything works fine. However, when I try to call it from inside the HTTP handler, everything returns some nonzero exit code (`ls` gives me `2`, `pwd` and `echo` give me `1`, etc.). Below is a complete, simple program that demonstrates this:

```
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_unix_daemon)).

:- use_module(library(process)).

:- initialization(start_server, main).

:- http_handler(root('run'), try_run, []).

start_server :-
    try_run(_),
    http_daemon([port(8080), user(root)]).

try_run(_Request) :-
    format('Content-type: text/plain~n~n', []),
    setup_call_cleanup(
        process_create(path(echo), ['hello world'], [process(PID)]),
        true,
        process_wait(PID, Code)),
    format('exited with: ~w~n', [Code]).
```

Obviously running as `root` isn't ideal, but I wanted to be sure there were no permission errors or anything.

Above, we can see that if we just run start the server, the call to `try_run/1` works inside `start_server/0`.

```
roei@roei-main:~$ swipl --version
SWI-Prolog version 8.0.3 for x86_64-linux
roei@roei-main:~/Prolog/website$ sudo swipl t.pl
Content-type: text/plain

hello world
exited with: exit(0)
```

But if I try to make a request:

```
roei@roei-main:~/Prolog/website$ curl -X POST localhost:8080/run
exited with: exit(1)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Are you aware of SWI-Prolog Discourse [forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/)? I don't know if you have an account there already as people often use different names on different accounts.

Comment: Saw [Issue with process_create/3 using the latest SWI-Prolog 8.1.19](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/issue-with-process-create-3-using-the-latest-swi-prolog-8-1-19/1664), but I know these kinds on question are not uncommon there.

Comment: @GuyCoder I wasn't, thanks; I just made an acocunt and posted it there too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that whatever `process_create/3` uses as the default output stream is not able to be written to, for whatever reason. But if I change it to:

```
try_run(_Request) :-
    format('Content-type: text/plain~n~n', []),
    setup_call_cleanup(
        process_create(path(echo), ['hello world'], [process(PID), stdout(pipe(Stream))]),
        true,
        process_wait(PID, Code)),
    current_output(Out),
    copy_stream_data(Stream, Out),
    format('exited with: ~w~n', [Code]).
```

i.e., manually setting up the output stream, it works now.